# C# Need help understanding strange Lambda construct

Tags: c#

Today I ran into this piece of code in a c# project:

```
public partial class LoginView : UserControl
    {
        public LoginView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += (s, e) => this.user.Focus();
        }
     ...
    }
```

this.Loaded is declared

```
public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
```

Ok, so we can add a event handler code taking two parameters, a sender s of type object and a RoutedEventArgs e. What actually is assigned is

```
public bool Focus ();
```

which seems to me to be a function taking no parameters and returning a boolean.

The code does obviously work, and I think I understand what it does (focus a textbox named "user" if this.loaded fires) but why is this code valid?

Thnx,

Armin.

Comment: You just ignore the `Focus();` method return value, this is completely valid in C# (if you don't need a return value)

Comment: Jep, so I thought. And, since ignoring parameters is as much fun as ignoring a return value, I declare s and e and ignore them as well. So how about (taken from anonymous function syntax of Object Pascal)

this.Loaded += @this.user.Focus();

Comment: `(s, e)` is part of delegate declaration, you can't omit them

Comment: But then the compiler should go nuts over me assigning a function which does not take *any* parameter. Ignoring the return value is standard in C#, through the absence of "sub" or "procedure", but omitting parameters?

Comment: @Nimral you can't omit function parameters, when invoke it or subscribe in delegaete, it will not compile

Comment: @Nimral You *aren't* assigning a function that doesn't take any parameters.  You're assigning a function that takes two parameters, ignores them, and calls another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning the `Focus` method to the `Loaded` delegate.
What the code is actually doing, is assigning a lambda to that delegate which conforms to the delegate definition.

The code

```
 this.Loaded += (s, e) => this.user.Focus();
```

is actually a shorthand for this:

```
 this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(FocusSomething);
```

and the `FocusSomething` method in the snippet above would be declared as

```
public void FocusSomething(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    this.user.Focus();
}
```

You're just 'ignoring' the return value of the `Focus` method, but the method that is assigned to the delegate has a void return type and accepts the 2 parameters (object and RoutedEventArgs so that's just valid).

Comment: Good explanation thanks, this changed my way of looking at the code given, and now everything is clear. I'd nevertheless, if I intend to write readable code, choose to do it the way you have described in your explanation...

Comment: There is a shorthand to the code that I've written in my answer; you can write it like this: `this.Loaded += FocusSomething;`

Answer (score 0):

So the `.Loaded` event does provide two parameters, but there is no requirement to use them in your lambda.  Depending on how your code is formatted they can be safely ignored.  In the same vein, while the `Focus()` method does return a value, there is no requirement to use it anywhere.  It's not very defensive and odds are the implementer provided the value for a reason, but strictly speaking it's not required from a language perspective.